# SQL return certain data from a search

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a automatic money transfer system for garrysmod.
I have a table similar to this: (Sorry for the table, HTML wasn't cooperating.

```
STEAMID                Name          wallet
STEAM 0 0 123456       ImNotLoved    $123456
STEAM 0 1 123456       ImAmLoved     $543214
```

I have a search box where you enter your `steamID` and I want it to search for the STEAM ID entered and return your current money. So for example if I entered my steam ID it would return on the next page, ImNotLoved, You currently have $123456 in your account. I got all the display knowledge, I just need a way to get the information from MySQL.

Comment: `SELECT wallet from MYTABLENAME where STEAMID = 'STEAM 0 0 123456' LIMIT 1 ;`  ? Are you looking for a simple SQL query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<form method="post" action="blah.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     Enter Steam Id: <input type="text" name="id">
     <input type="submit">
<form>
```

blah.php:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$bal=mysql_query("select wallet from tablename where STEAMID = ".$id);
$balance=mysql_fetch_row($bal);
$name=mysql_query("select Name from tablename where STEAMID = ".$id);
$nam=mysql_fetch_row($name);
echo "Welcome ".$nam['Name']."! You currently have ".$balance['wallet']." in your account";
```

Comment: You can write this query in one line as follows:                        $query = sprintf("select name, wallet from tablename where STEAMID =  %d LIMIT 1".$id);                                     $result=mysql_query($query);                                                         $data = mysql_fetch_row($result);                                  echo "Welcome ".$data[0]."! You currently have ".$data[1]." in your account";

Comment: `mysql_query` doesn't return the value from the DB, you have to call a fetch function like `mysql_fetch_row`. Also, the mysql extension is depreceated, you should use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @Barmar Using frameworks like codeigniter,pns made me forget about stuff like fetching ;). in those frameworks executing the query itself gives the result

Comment: @AtulRai Using frameworks like codeigniter,pns made me forget about stuff like fetching ;). in those frameworks executing the query itself gives the result